# How to delete rows based on field value but not if certain other field values Dont exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on a financial reporting table for my business and trying to "massage" the data into something the parent company wants to read. I am VERY close.

Essentially, I have this:

```
Account FPeriod    Balance
   1          0      42
   1          1      53
   1          2      11
   2          0      62
   3          0     567
   3          1     564
   3          2      34
```

where each account has multiple rows, one for each fiscal period it has transactions in.
Fiscal period 0 represents the opening balance of the account for the fiscal year.

What I need to do is delete rows with fiscal period 0 but not if it is the only entry for that account.

I have done:

```
Delete from TABLE  
WHERE Fperiod = 0
```

but this removes all the rows with FPeriod 0 where for instance i need to keep account 2 FPeriod 0 as it's the only entry for that account. I do need to delete account 1 and 3 FPeriod 0 rows.

I am not even sure where to begin, thinking maybe a while loop? I hear those are bad if you can avoid them.

I need the output to look like this:

```
Account FPeriod    Balance
       1          1      53
       1          2      11
       2          0      62
       3          1     564
       3          2      34
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cteBase as (
Select * 
      ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By Account Order By FPeriod Desc)
 From YourTable 
) 
Select * From cteBase where RowNr>1 and FPeriod=0
-- Delete From cteBase where RowNr>1 and FPeriod=0
```

If you are happy with the results switch the final select with the Delete

From your sample, these two records would be deleted

```
Account FPeriod Balance 
1       0       42      
3       0       567
```

Comment: @GrahamTylerPurchase Happy to help.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE  
WHERE Fperiod = 0
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM TABLE t1 
            WHERE t1.Account = TABLE.Account 
             AND  t1.FPeriod > 0)
```